# How to send a whole prepared HTTP request in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I've got a prepared HTTP request like the following:

```
POST /cgi-bin/process.cgi HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE5.01; Windows NT)
Host: www.tutorialspoint.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: length
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive

licenseID=string&content=string&/paramsXML=string
```

I need to send this whole request to the destination in Javascript, and wouldn't like to have to convert it to a JSON object, and then pass it to a function such as `fetch`. How can I do that?

Comment: Why not use AJAX?

Comment: So you do not want to use fetch? Then you will need to do a good old XMLHttpRequest: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: I've actually copied an entire request from my browser, and need to resend it in NodeJS for some purpose.

Comment: "and wouldn't like to have to convert it to a JSON object", what do you mean by this?  No JSON is necessary...

Comment: @some_guy Why *would* you use AJAX?  It hasn't been needed in a decade, thanks to the modern Fetch API.

Comment: @Brad AJAX (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML) typically refers to any async request initiated from client-side code. The acronym has been distorted since its inception but I don't think the first comment necessarily refers to XMLHttpRequest

Comment: @Brad The `fetch` API is only around 8 years old at this time, so `XMLHttpRequest` certainly has been needed in the last decade

Answer (score 3):

Fetch API is fine.

```js
fetch('http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cgi-bin/process.cgi', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE5.01; Windows NT)',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    // etc.
  }
  body: 'licenseID=string&content=string&/paramsXML=string'
});
```

Comment: I have copied a request from my browser, and need to resend it in NodeJS for some purpose. If I want to use fetch function, then I have to decompose the whole request string to method, headers, and body, and I don't want to do this extra work.

Comment: @HedayatMahdipour Why not?  It's far easier for you to reformat your raw on-the-wire HTTP request data as real request data than it would be to deal with rolling your own HTTP stuff.  If you insist... then just make a TCP connection to the server and send your data over the socket.  But, I would not go that route these days.  You'd lose compatibility with modern HTTP protocols, for example.  Plus, you'd have to figure out how to deal with the responses which is not as trivial as it seems.

Comment: @HedayatMahdipour "*I have copied a request from my browser*" - actually modern browsers let you copy the request as a `fetch` command

Comment: Just a small correction... the URL should be `http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cgi-bin/process.cgi` to accomodate the `Host` header